# Can't Remember the Title of an Urban Fantasy Vampire Novel

Tags: story-identification, vampire, urban-fantasy

The book starts with a woman who kills 'bad' vampires while her tech of a brother stays in the car.  When her brother quits to get married, she ends up working alone.  I remember she is hurt and the lead 'good' vampire heals her on a plane.  She ends up going to a paranormal party where she sees the ambassador or something killed by the vampire who killed her mom, but who is supposedly dead.  She, the 'good' vampire, and a shape-shifting detective hunt him down after he kills one of their friends, and the bad guy is a semi-immortal who was her date and is using his own sister's blood to stay alive.  She gets tortured by the 'bad' vampire and almost dies, but the one who likes her ultimately turns her.

Sorry, I'm really bad with names.

I was also wondering if it is stand alone or part of a series

Comment: Sounds a little like the Anita Blake series.

Comment: @Zoe, except for everything after "a woman who kills 'bad' vampires".  No brother, no healing on a plane, mother wasn't killed by vampires, etc.

Comment: Eh, yeah. Just the shape-shifter bit, and paranormal party, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're talking about [Night's Cold Kiss](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061783137) by Tracey O'Hara. It's one of the books from the Dark Brethren series.

> The tension between the Aeternus, an ancient vampiric people, and humanity has been mounting for over a century. But when rogue vampires begin to drain humans in order to achieve an illegal blood-high, all bets are off.
>
>  After the death of her parents, Antoinette Petrescu devoted her life to becoming one of the top Venators, the elite hunters who destroy the rogue Necrodreniacs. Her kill count is legendary and her skills superb.
>
>   But now the serial killer who killed her parents has returned. And to stop him Antoinette must join forces not only with the Aeternus, but also their most legendary killer. One that is both dangerously attractive, and involved in buried secrets of her past. More dangerous still, a dark attraction grows between them--one that could doom both races.